# SharePoint Change OK button text to Submit in newitem.aspx of lists

Tags: sharepoint

I have a problem with the sharepoint lists. I need to change the OK button to display as Submit. Anyone has any ideas how to do that?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In your URL box, after NewForm.aspx (or EditForm.aspx,) add this text: `?toolpaneview=2`
    Your url should look like "`http://mysite.com/mylist/NewForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2`"

2) Hit enter. The page will open in Shared editing mode. Choose "Add a Web Part" anywhere on the page.

3) Add a Content Editor Web Part. In the Text Source of the Content Editor Web Part, paste the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeOKButtons()
{
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
 for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) 
 { 
  if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "OK") 
   inputs[i].value = "Submit"; 
 } 
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeOKButtons");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use the jQuery equivalent of zincorp's code:

```
function changeButton()
{
    $("input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") === "ButtonName") {
            $(this).attr("value", "NewButtonName");
        }
    });
}
```

And if you have jQuery 1.6 or greater, use "prop" instead of "attr".